# Win32 ISO C example how to switch current process from Administrator account to account "MYFOOBAR"?

Tags: windows, winapi, mingw

I am looking for Win32 API (Windows 8+) example written in ISO C which shows how to switch current process from Administrator account to account "MYFOOBAR" ?

I need to switch from an user account with admin rights to another account (FOOBAR, chicken.monster, MYFOOBAR, SYSTEM etc.), using just plain Win32 API.

What does NOT work in the following example is |LogOnUserA()| for special local accounts like "SYSTEM":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void get_file_size(std::string path)
{
    struct _stat fileinfo;
    _stat(path.c_str(), &fileinfo);
    std::cout << "file size is " << fileinfo.st_size << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    HANDLE  tokenHandle;
    puts("#mark0");
    bool returnValue = LogonUserA("SYSTEM", NULL, NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &tokenHandle);
    if (false == returnValue) {
        return 1;
    }
    puts("#mark1");
    bool res = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(tokenHandle);
    if (res)
    {
        std::string path = "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\getent.exe";
        puts("#mark2");
        get_file_size(path);
        
        RevertToSelf();
    }
    puts("#mark3");
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this as Administrator |LogonUserA()| just fails... ;-(

Comment: wahat you mean under *switch* ? if you know credentials from *MYFOOBAR* (like login/password) you can create token for *MYFOOBAR* and than impersonate thread in current process with this token or create new process with this token. also in domain, if you have admin rigths, you can use *S4U* logon without knowledge of user credentials.  but this logon/token can access only local resources.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844584/is-there-an-api-call-to-prompt-user-for-uac-elevation

Comment: @BrechtSanders this is question, how run as another user, not how run elevated (but as same user)

Comment: I was referring to that link mostly for the use of the functions `LogonUser()`/`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`/`RevertToSelf()`